# How to load spash screen when app loading from background in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, expo, screen, native, splash-screen

I'm using react native expo to build a app. I have faced a big problem right now.
I want to load splash screen when app is loading from background.
scenario,

1. When I open app, it load splash screen, then go to home screen.
2. Then use hardware back button to go to app background then again open app

Right now when I load app from background always show home screen before load splash screen

I try to kill the app when use hardware back button using `BackHandler.exitApp()` its not killing the app.

I want to load splash screen first and then go to home screen.

Can any body help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the Expo Documentation on SplashScreens https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/ and https://docs.expo.io/guides/splash-screens/. If these aren't as helpful, you should post a code snippet of your main App screen and the code which you used to integrate and hide the splash screen when the application loads.

Comment: Thanks for update. The problem  here is, when reopen the app (it already in the recent apps), it reload home screen without going through the render code. It just load from like a cache data. 
So changes not affected. 
I used AppState to manage the state. I used AppState, when app goes background and when app come back to foreground that logic not executing.

Comment: I think you should try running 'SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()' before the function you want to run and finally run ' SplashScreen.hideAsync()' when the lines of code you want to run end. (This can be in componentDidMount() after the parts of code you want to run)